# Axios GET request to url that has a htpasswd

Tags: javascript, axios, httprequest

I'm using Axios to make a GET request to a URL that has a htpasswrd. I'm getting a CORS policy error back in DevTools when making the request, which I think is due to the GET request not getting past the htpasswrd. I thought the correct way to pass the htaccess username and password to the endpoint is by using the 'auth' config option, as follows:

```
axios.get('https://example.com/api', {
    auth: {
        username: 'htusername',
        password: 'htpassword'
    }
}).then(response =>
{
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

This doesn't work though. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: What **exactly** does the CORS related error message say?

Comment: I get:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/api' from origin 'http://localhost:3006' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: That's unusual. I'd expect that an OPTIONS request there would fail with either a 403 error because you demand credentials on the preflight or would pass. That you are returning a 200 OK for it without `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is rather weird. You really need to do some debugging of the HTTP requests (use the Network tab in the browser's developer tools) and whatever server-side code generates them.

Answer (score 0):

All sorted - I had to pass the htaccess username and password (URL encoded) into the URL and then set the 'withCredentials' option to true too. Here's an example:

```
axios.get(
    'https://urlencodedusername:password@thedomain.com/api',
    {
        withCredentials: true
    }
).then(response=>
{
    console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try accessing your link like this:

```js
axios.get(`https://${username}:${password}@example.com/api`)
```

Comment: Why should that work if the instructions in the axios documentation that the OP is following don't?

Comment: Then what about sending an Authorization Cookie with a Basic Base64 encoded string? Anyway it seems that the endpoint he's trying to reach is not allowing his Origin

Comment: How would they send an Authorization Cookie? JS is forbidden from manually setting a Cookie header on a request.

Comment: Oh is it? Never saw that anywhere

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name

Comment: I messed up, it's not about a Cookie but an Authorization **Header**